# Intersection Observer: can't implement observer.unobserve(image);

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

```
const imagez = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery__image");

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.7,
};

function handleImg(myImg, observer) {
  myImg.forEach((myImgSingle) => {
    console.log(myImgSingle.intersectionRatio);
    if (myImgSingle.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      loadImage(myImgSingle.target);
    }
  });
}

function loadImage(image) {
  image.src = image.getAttribute("data-source");
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleImg, options);

imagez.forEach((img) => {
  observer.observe(img);
});

imagez.forEach((img) => {
  observer.unobserve(img);
});
```

HTML

```
<img class="gallery__image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/13/10/36/mountains-3674334_1280.jpg" data-source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/13/10/36/mountains-3674334_1280.jpg" alt="Alpine Mountains" data-index="22">
```

Can't rightly implement observer.unobserve(). Have tried to put it in a separate function , but in this case I can't load all the pics. Please explain what should I change in my code to stop observing.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to unsubscribe? What has to trigger this?

Comment: I'd like to stop observing when everything is already observed, and all of the images have been loaded @Lynx242